# Trying to filter the ACF post object to display certain pages only

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to filter the pages listed on the post object field to display only pages that are in an array.

I managed to get it to work using a relationship field. However, i need to make a reverse query and need to use the post object field.

This is the code is used for the relationship field query filter

```
function my_relationship_query( $args, $field, $post )
{
// increase the posts per page
$args['post__in'] = array(32,14); //works!
return $args;
}

// filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=where_used','my_relationship_query', 10, 3);
```

And here is the code I tried to use for the post object query which no matter what i do or change it does not change the results in the dropdown (all pages are always listed in the dropdown).

```
function my_post_object_query( $args, $field, $post_id ) {

// only show children of the current post being edited
$args['post__in'] = array(32,14);;


// return
return $args;

}


// filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/name=where_used', 'my_post_object_query', 10, 3);
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_relationship_query( $args, $field, $post ) {
    // only show children of the current post being edited
    $args['post_parent'] = $post->ID;
    return $args;
}

// filter for every field
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=relationship_field_name', 'my_relationship_query', 10, 3);
```